# Add Trace file in windows service

Tags: c#

I want to add a trace file in my windows service but the file is never created. Is this only meant for web applications?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
  <startup>
   <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
     <listeners>
      <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Logs\application.log" />
      <remove name="Default" />
     </listeners>
    </trace>
   </system.diagnostics>
  </startup>
 </configuration>
```

In code

```
Trace.WriteLine("Application started.", "App");
```

Answer (score 2):

The config file you show is invalid. Under the [`startup` element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h(v=vs.110).aspx) only settings for the runtime are allowed.

The [system.diagnostics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1txedc80(v=vs.110).aspx) goes directly under the `<config>` element, like so:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
     <listeners>
      <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Logs\application.log" />
      <remove name="Default" />
     </listeners>
    </trace>
   </system.diagnostics>
 </configuration>
```

Depending on the [security context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x72fzyf(v=vs.110).aspx) for your service you might have to set permissions on the folder where you want to log, in your case `c:\logs`. The Tracing will silently fail if it can't write to that log file.